# Spring: Http406 The resource identified by this request is only capable

Tags: java, spring, http, tomcat

I use Spring4.0.0,SpringMVC ,and I have `jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar,jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar`.

> The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.

My Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="login.do",method= RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ServerResponse<User> login(String username, String password, HttpSession session){
    ServerResponse<User> response = iUserService.login(username,password);
    if(response.isSuccess()){
        session.setAttribute(Const.CURRENT_USER,response.getData());
    }
    return response;
}
```

My dispatcher-servlet.xml already have the content.These are part of file.

```
 xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd

 <mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                <list>
                    <value>text/plain;charset=UTF-8</value>
                    <value>text/html;charset=UTF-8</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                <list>
                    <value>application/json;charset=UTF-8</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

But I use debug it.It's OK.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Adzds.png)

then I use web ,it doesn't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF8PH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Debug pic you need the `User` and I'm guessing `json`-ised.

Simply return the `User` and not `ServerResponse<User>`.

Comment: The `response` is my json data, I need `response` not `User` ,because `User` is only user's data, it hasn't `msg`,'status','data'.